# What's the best/shortest way to log SqlCommand CommandText and Parameters and SqlDataReader fields with Serilog?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, logging, serilog

I would like to log the CommandText and the Parameters (only names and values) from a SqlCommand.
I would like to log even the fields names with values from a SqlDataReader.
I've tried with the following code but the command log is too verbose with a lot of unnecessary properties and the reader log doesn't enumerate all the fields, just the total count.
There is some way I can customize the output? Or somebody have already created an extension for this?

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("myconnectionstring"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("select somefield from sometable where anotherfield = @filtername", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("filtername", "somevalue");
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    try
    {
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "Error on ExecuteReader {@command}", command);
        return;
    }
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        try
        {
            /* some code */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Error on reading {@reader}", reader);
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: You can customize it however you want, you are not obligated to provide a single object to the logger. You will have to write some code to obtain only the data you want from those objects.

Comment: By the way [`AddWithValue` is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and you should be disposing your reader with `using`

Answer (score 0):

Write your own logging class that declares objects that only have the properties you are interested in logging and then pass those objects into the call to SeriLog. This code illustrates the principle only, it was not tested or guaranteed to be free of syntax / logic errors.

## Custom logging class

```
public static class MyCustomLogger {

  private class MyCustomSqlException {
    public string Message {get; set;}
    public string Query {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string,string> Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  }

  private class MyCustomSqlReaderException {
    public string Message {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string,string> Fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  }

  public static void LogSqlException(
    Exception ex, 
    string query, 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection Parameters parameters) {

    MyCustomSqlException myex = new MyCustomSqlException()
    {
      Message = ex.Message,
      Query = query
    }

    foreach(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter p in parameters) {
      Parameters.Add(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
    }

    Log.Error("A SQL exception occurred", myex);
  }

  public static void LogSqlReaderException(
    Exception ex, 
    SqlDataReader reader) {

    MyCustomSqlReaderException myex = new MyCustomSqlReaderException()
    {
      Message = ex.Message
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < reader.FieldCount; x++) {
      Fields.Add(reader.GetName(x), reader.GetValue(x).ToString());
    }

    Log.Error("A SQL reading exception occurred", myex);
  }
}
```

## Implementation

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("myconnectionstring"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("select somefield from sometable where anotherfield = @filtername", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("filtername", "somevalue");
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    try
    {
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MyCustomLogger.LogSqlException(ex, command.CommandText, command.Parameters);
        return;
    }
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        try
        {
            /* some code */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyCustomLogger.LogSqlReaderException(ex, reader);
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: I highly discourage writing your own logger. There are many nuances and land mines to doing logging well and you really should use a library that knows what it is doing.

Comment: Good point. This class is a wrapper to be used for the specific requirements stated in the question - specifically logging sql exceptions resulting from command execution, and exceptions originating from logic that processes a data reader. It is not a new implementation of logging. It is also kind of pointless given that the SeriLog package already does what the fabrizio needs, which is to only serialize specific properties of specific object types.

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm going to use something like this, but I found awkward have to write all this code everytime.
I'm still looking for a better way.

```cs
try
{
    using (SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                /* some code */
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Debug(ex, "{@fiels}", Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount).ToDictionary(i => dr.GetName(i), i => dr.GetValue(i)));
                throw new ApplicationException(null, ex);
            }
        }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(ex, "{query}\n{@parameters}", com.CommandText, com.Parameters.Cast<SqlParameter>().ToDictionary(x => x.ParameterName, x => x.Value));
}
```

Edit 1: and this is for DataRow logging

```cs
DataTable dt = /* some logic to load dt */
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        /* some code */
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Debug(ex, "{@items}", dr.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(x => x.ColumnName, x => dr[x.ColumnName]));
    }
}
```

Edit 2: I'm using this extensions now but I'm still not happy

```cs
static class SerilogExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> Log(this SqlParameterCollection p)
    {
        return p.Cast<SqlParameter>().ToDictionary(x => x.ParameterName, x => x.Value);
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, object> Log(this SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount).ToDictionary(i => dr.GetName(i), i => dr.GetValue(i));
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, object> Log(this DataRow dr)
    {
        return dr.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(x => x.ColumnName, x => dr[x.ColumnName]);
    }
}

/* usage */
Log.Error(ex, "{query}\n{@parameters}", com.CommandText, com.Parameters.Log());
```